# RabbitMQ model for "is anyone listening able to process this?"

Tags: design-patterns, rabbitmq

I have two webservers and multi-master MySQL database behind them. I'm trying to avoid a race condition by using RabbitMQ, and I'm not sure how I should be setting up the exchange/queue. I hope someone can point me in the right direction:

When we get the race condition, 
User is on WWW1, creates a record for a purchase on WWW1 (via a load balancer), and we send them off-site to process their payment. The third-party payment processor calls the load balancer which directs it to WWW2 to update the record with payment information. Sometimes WWW2's database server hasn't gotten the replication updates from WWW1's database server, and it can't process the payment. This is when everything falls apart.

I would like to have the method that processes the payment simply tell RabbitMQ that "Transaction 12345 has been paid" and have subscribers attached to both databases *try* to see if they *can* process the message (it's OK if they both do), and for that method to know whether or not any subscriber could process the payment information or not.

Comment: Can you take the payment information and put it into a queue and process it from there?  This would give you a chance at retrying the payment information if the other updates have not yet arrived.

Comment: So, using the previous example, when www2 gets the message and fails to be able to do anything about it, queue it up and either www1 will get it, or www2 will get it again and hopefully this is after database replication has happened?

Comment: I would say put it into the queue immediately and if it fails, send it back to the queue.  Keep retrying for a configurable number of times before sending it to a dead letter queue to be worked later (maybe manually).  This would require keeping track of retries maybe on a header of the message.